# STL vectors, push_back() and capacity

Tags: c++, vector, capacity

I was wondering if the capacity carries over when one pushes a vector onto a vector of vectors.

Say i have a code that looks like

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > >  vec_of_vec;
std::vector< int > tmp;

for (int i = 0 ; i < 100; ++i) {
   foo(tmp,i); // fills tmp with an arbitrary number of ints, different for each i.
   vec_of_vec.push_back(tmp);
   tmp.clear();
}
```

Now, since `.clear()` does not reduce capacity, if one particular instance of `tmp` is smaller than `tmp.capacity()`, will `tmp.capacity()` shrink to fit `tmp.size()` once it is pushed back onto `vec_of_vec`? i.e. which constructor does push_back calls, and is capacity modified in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacity of the item pushed back `vec_of_vec.back()`, is implementation defined.

However, since `tmp` is copied into `vec_of_vec` (using the copy constructor), the original `tmp` object's capacity is unchanged in the `vec_of_vec.push_back()` call.

Comment: Thanks! 
I guess I could have guessed the answer by reading the "duplicate" questions :). I was confused there, didn't realize the copy constructor was bound to be called.
I threw a shrink_to_fit() call in there to make sure vec_of_vec.back() is always a tight fit, regardless of the implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really feel this was a duplicate, you had a very specific question that wasn't immediately obvious by reading the duplicates and their answers.

Answer (score 0):

`push_back` copies it's argument into `vec_of_vec` so `tmp` no longer references what's in `vec_of_vec` so it's the copy constructor that's called